# Should I avoid package singletons in golang?

Tags: go, singleton, global-variables

at the moment I have a package `store` with following content:

```
package store

var (
    db *Database
)

func Open(url string) error {
    // open db connection
}

func FindAll(model interface{}) error {
    // return all entries
}

func Close() {
    // close db connection
}
```

This allows me to use `store.FindAll` from other packages after I have done `store.Open` in `main.go`.

However as I saw so far most packages prefer to provide a struct you need to initialize yourself. There are only few cases where this global approach is used.

**What are downsides of this approach and should I avoid it?**

Comment: Note that some packages, like the standard library's `log` package, provide a global logger, but ALSO allow you to construct additional, independent loggers. (The package API is just a wrapper over the struct).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard `http` package has a `ServerMux` for generic usecases and but also has one default instance of `ServerMux` called `DefaultServerMux` (http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-variables) for convenience. So that when you call `http.HandleFunc` it creates the handler on the default mux. You can find the same approach used in `log` and many other packages. This is essentially your "singleton" approach.

However, I don't think it's a good idea to follow that pattern in your use case, since the users need to call `Open` regardless of the default database. And, because of that, using a default instance would not really help and instead would actually make it less convenient:

```
d := store.Open(...)
defer d.Close()
d.FindAll(...)
```

is much easier to both write and read than:

```
store.Open(...)
defer store.Close()
store.FindAll(...)
```

And, also there are semantic problems: what should happen if someone calls `Open` twice:

```
store.Open(...)
defer store.Close()
...
store.Open(...)
store.FindAll(...) // Which db is this referring to?
```

Comment: I'm sorry about this snarky comment almost 7 years later. It is *NOT* easier to read your first code block compared to your second in all cases. If you replace `store` with `government`, or something that is a singleton, you almost always have to Open and Close the singleton, and not an instance. Whether singletons are a good design pattern with Go is an entirely different topic that is application-specific.

Answer (score 5):

1. You can't instantiate connections to 2 storages at once.
2. You can't easily mock out storage in unit tests of dependent code using convenient tools like gomock.

Comment: are there any dos-and-dont's for go? I feel still a bit insecure in terms of architecture :/

Comment: Global variables are generally bad. This isn't go specific and doesn't have anything to do with architecture.