# Idiomatic naming convention for exported struct and getter for the whole struct in Go

Tags: go, struct, getter

When I have a struct like the following:

```golang
// user.go
package user

type User struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
    // other fields
}

func NewUser() User {
    return User{ID: 1+1}
}

// for user list I can do it like this:
func Users() []User {
    // ...
    // return list of users
}

// But for sing user, what is the idiomatic way to name a getter here?
// Getter 1
func GetUser(id) User {
    // return the user that has the provided id
}

// Getter 2
func Get(id) User {
    // return the user that has the provided id
}

// Getter 3
func ByID(id) User {
    // return the user that has the provided id
}

// Getter 4
func OfID(id) User {
    // return the user that has the provided id
}
```

In another package I can use it like so:

```golang
package somepackage

import "user"


func doStuff() {
    u := user.NewUser()
    // do stuff
}

func doOtherStuff() {
    users = user.Users()
    for _, u := range users {
        // do other stuff
    }
}

func checkUser(useID int) {
    // Get the user of the `userID` id
    // this way?:
    u := user.GetUser(useID)

    // or this way?:
    u := user.Get(userID)

    // or?:
    u := user.ByID(userID)

    // or?:
    u := user.OfID(userID)
}
```

Off course I'd like to use something like:

```golang
u.User(id)
```

But that is not possible as the name `User` is used by the struct.

So what is the idiomatic way to name a getter in this case? Or should rename the struct to something else *which I prefer not to*?

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from defining a `User` method with a `User` receiver.

Comment: @EmilePels I've edited the context of the question, I was in a hurry and copied the code of the wrong context! Apologize!

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account what is suggested by [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#package-names) the `user` package code could look like this:

```
package user

type (
  User struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
    // other fields
  }
  
  Users []User
}

// New creates new User.
func New() User {
    // Initialize User structure.
    return User{ID: 1 + 1}
}

// AdminUsers returns users with admin privileges.
func AdminUsers() Users {
   return Users{....}
}

func (l Users) Find(id int) (User, bool) {
  for i := range l {
    if l[i].ID == id {
       return l[id], true
    }
  }
  return User{}, false
}
```

I renamed `NewUser` to `New` as the user suffix duplicates the name of package here.

The `Users` function does not bring any value here. As i understand it returns some list but the name does not tells what is the purpose of having this list. I replaced it with `Users` type with a method for finding user on this list by id and example `AdminUsers` function which returns a list of admin user (in practice it will probably be repository and you will grab the whole list from the database every time).

The last part is the getter, which in my opinion is useless here, because getter will return exactly the same User as what you have in hand. Example:

```
u := user.New()
u1 := u.User()
// u1 == u
```

Comment: The functionality of `Find` is the one I want it to be in the `u.User(id)` getter. I like the idea of applying it on the `Users` type, didn't think of that. What I'm trying to do is to set the receiver `u of User` to be the user with the passed `id`.

Comment: So you want to have a setter instead of getter? Am i correct? If so then then the document says that it should be something like `SetID()`. But it only make sense when assigning an ID requires some extra logic. Otherwise you can omit setter with `u.ID = id`

Comment: No, just a getter. Sorry, I should point out in my previous comment that I've edited the question to have the correct context. I was in a hurry and I messed up the context and confused everyone including my self. Sorry again!

Comment: Oh, then i must ask you few question. First of what is the intention of this method, whether it should return existing user or create new one with given id? It the first one how do you want to implement this on the package level? Normally you have something like user repository with various method to fetch user. It is up to the user, sometimes frameworks specifies how the method should look like. I saw `Find`, `FindOne`, `Get`, `GetByID`, `ByID`. More or less what you have mentioned in the question.

Comment: The intention of this method is just to return an existing user by id, not to create a new one. I have a few methods in the package, only one method to return a user, the user is returned from a map that uses user id as key `map[int]User` (`return usersmap[id]`)

Comment: I would advise against putting a method to fetch a user at the package level. First, you won't be able to have multiple maps, because the package-level function acts like a singleton. Secondly you will have difficult unit tests, and if you run them in parallel they may give wrong results.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point! What do you mean by "putting a method to fetch a user at the package level"? Is there another way to get a user from a map, a list, or even from database? I'm really starving to learn best practices with go.

Comment: Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583542/should-i-avoid-package-singletons-in-golang). This is what you probably encounter with functions on a package level. In general the topic refers to package level variables not functions, but in your situation this is still valid as the functions must use package level variables (list, map, db handler) to work.

Comment: I get you. But actually I don't have any package level variables beside couple constants I use as enums, the map is generated inside a private function that returns group of users from log files (20 user in each file, file names are the id of the first user in the file)